# How to add a new method to a controller in asp.net webAPI 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) tutorial on www.asp.net to learn about .net web api 2. I added a second lookup on the index page:

```
    <div>
    <h2>Search by Category</h2>
    <input type="text" id="catId" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="findCat();" />
    <p id="categories" />
</div>
```

and modified the existing javascript to add a lookup for category. The idea being to enter a category (eg, Toys) and the API would return the products in that category:

```
    function findCat() {
    var uri = 'api/GetCategory';
    var cid = $('#catId').val();

    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + cid)
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#categories').text(formatItem(data));
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#categories').text('Error: ' + err);
        });
}
```

I added a method in the controller class that (I thought) would handle this:

```
        public IHttpActionResult GetCategory(string Category)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((c) => c.Category == Category);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

When I run a search on category it is unable to find the products in that category. What am I missing (besides about 6 months of study! I know!)

Thank you

Comment: What's in your WebApiConfig config.Routes.MapHttpRoute?

Comment: does your call actually hit the method "GetCategory" when you debug it ?

Comment: common things, like @Omar.Alani said, does it have a product, are you getting NotFound back or another error, Case-sensitive..

Comment: @RageCompex I'm actually getting a NotFound. dan asked what is in my routes config and that is likely where the problem lies as I only have the defaulApi in there. I'll hit the books some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your comments you tell us that you only have the defaultApi in the route configuration, that would be:

```
 api/{controller}/{id}
```

You also tell us that you get a `NotFound` error, I guess that this happens because it cannot find the controller/method.

By reading your script you are actually doing this:

```js
    function findCat() {         //actual request URL:
    var uri = 'api/GetCategory'; //api/GetCategory/ 
    var cid = $('#catId').val(); 

    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + cid)  //api/GetCategory/1
```

You use `GetCategory` as controller, which is not correct, your controller is the class name + Controller. So in your case probably `ProductController`

Secondly, WebApi doesn't look for method names, it only looks for a distinction in **HTTP-request type** and **parameters**. So if you have two methods with different names but they are both a `GET` request-type and both have a int as parameter, Web Api doesn't know which one to use.

Your api link should be: `api/Product?category="blabla"`

What you can do is add additional routing to a method, the default `AccountController` gives good examples for this.

In your case:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Product")] //you have to specify this if you would like to do custom routing.
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    //GET: api/Product/Category?category="blabla"
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Category")] //route constraint
    public IHttpActionResult GetCategory(string category)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((c) => c.Category == Category);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }

}
```

So now you can update your script, your script is made for getting something by Id, while you want this to be by string, you can probably figure it out. Something like this I guess (not that good with javascript yet.

```js
function findCat() {
var uri = 'api/Product/Category';
var cid = $('#catName').valueOf();

$.getJSON(uri + '?category=' + cid)
    .done(function (data) {
        $('#categories').text(formatItem(data));
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#categories').text('Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

*Optional:* If you like to have you link like this: `api/Product/Category/blabla` you have to add this:

```cs
[Route("Category/{category}")]
```

Web API Routing: [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) 
Attribute routing and constraints: [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)